# STM32 bare-metal programming - Memory addressing in 32-bit system - memory offset

Tags: stm32, arm, memory, register

I am coming from a mechanical background and some Atmega experience, now doing some bare-metal programming courses on ARM processors. So far it is looking great, digging into documentation about uC functional structure, toggling bits of correct address etc.

But I never paid too much attention (until now) to memory structure and addresses.

Looking at the offset (see pic below), you can see that the offset between each consequent register is 0x004.

My question is, why the 0x004 offset? What does 0x004 mean? 32-bit registers have 4 bytes, is that the reason why?

I haven't found any material online, also considering the RM0468 Reference Manual from ST.

Thanks for all the feedback! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the registers are typically 32-bit and that is 4 bytes, and as memory is accessed at byte granularity, usually the distance between two registers is 4 bytes.

Note that the offset is just addition to the peripheral base address, because it's easier to have say 10 timers or 6 UARTs and while they each are at different base address in the 32-bit memory space, the peripherals are othrrwise identical.

Comment: As an example in one of other ASICs I am dealing with. 
Registers are of size 24bits. However the offset between them is 0x01.
I am geting confused again :)

Comment: @AljazJelen: Welcome to the multiple meanings of the word "byte".  In some contexts it is an octet (exactly 8 bits), on UART pins (but not in the memory map) it's between 5 and 8 data bits, plus start stop and optional parity.  And in the C standard it's "the smallest addressable unit of memory".  In your ASIC, it sounds like the smallest addressable unit is a 24-bit register.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at the offset (see pic below), you can see that offset between
> each consequent register is 0x004. My question is, why the 0x004
> offset? What does 0x004 mean? 32 bit registers have 4 bytes, is that
> the reason why?

Yes, that is the reason.  The STM32 ARM architecture is 32-bit which means that it natively reads and writes 32-bit values from memory and I/O ports.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer :)
But my confusion is the following. 0x004 (or simply 4) is insufficient to cover a byte. A byte covers up to integer 7 or in other words 0x0 - 0x7. 
So to have an offset of 32 bits (for next register), i would assume an offset of 0x20, which equals 32 in DEC.
What am I thinking wrong here? :)

Comment: @AljazJelen " A byte covers up to integer 7 " Could you please clarify that? There are 4 bytes in 32 bits. Each memory address refers to a byte (0, 1, 2 and 3, than the next word).

Comment: @AljazJelen "What am I thinking wrong here?"* It seems you are indexing bits not bytes. Each byte has an address, not each bit.

Comment: hi @devnull, sorry for confussion, I dont know what I was thinking, when writing that statement down.
What I mean, that byte contains 8 bits. So you need 4 bytes to offset 32 bits. And if you down in hex, how many bits you need to offset for 32 bits, it would be 0x20 and not 0x4.
But, if the offset refers to how many "bytes" you offset, then the 0x4 would be an answer yes.
I just dont understand, why are we offsetting bytes. I somehow expected, that we always refers to bits.

Comment: @AljazJelen: If you've never taken classes on computer architecture, then the nomenclature will be foreign to you.  Perhaps look for [basic info online](http://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/~zheng/ece5362/lecture-notes/Lecture5.pdf), etc.

Comment: Hi @toolic, I had a look at the slides. If I accept the point given on the slide 5: 
"Byte addressable machine is almost universal
- Successive addresses refer to successive byte locations"  then all my questions are clarified :)